# Newbie, scraping table from url and not able to get output in python command prompt

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

This is a homework assignment, I have to sum up all the data in the span tag and print it, I took out all the info in the span tag and appended it to a list, I dont know how to go beyond that as any funtion I type out of the for loop does not function, also I have to hit enter twice after I run this in the python command prompt to get an output

I am new here, please forgive the format of the question, thanks for the help

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
lst = list()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
spans = soup.findAll('span', attrs = {'class' : 'comments'})
for span in spans:
    num = int(span.text)
    lst.append(num)
    print(num)
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I did not have to press enter twice for the output to appear. What environment are you using? Also, it would help if you showed the function you tried to call outside the for loop for us to know why it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

No need to collect to list or anything if you just adding them together. You can do it like this:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
lst = list()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
spans = soup.findAll('span', attrs = {'class' : 'comments'})
sum = 0
for span in spans:
    sum += int(span.text)

print("Total Sum = " + str(sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have prepared the list of numbers in span, you can have the sum of numbers using `sum()` function in python. Pass your list as argument of `sum()`.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
lst = list()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
spans = soup.findAll('span', attrs = {'class' : 'comments'})
for span in spans:
    num = int(span.text)
    lst.append(num)
    print(num)

sum_of_nums = sum(lst)
print(sum_of_nums)
```